# What pieces are involved in managing sub domains DNS records in this example

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, dns-hosting

I'm trying to educate myself on DNS management, trying to get the big picture on large domain names architectures. If this is not the right place to ask this kind of question, please let me know!

Let's say we have example.com, serving different services like www.example.com, service1.example.com, service2.example.com from a central point (servers cluster, with something like nginx managing the routes, balancing etc...).

Now let's say we also have numerous other clusters (regionA.example.com, regionB.example.com), hosted elsewhere, providing customized services (www.regionA.example.com, service3.regionA.example.com, ...).

These regional servers get added/deleted/modified regularly, their IP can change, and we want to avoid manual configuration.

A few very basic (but broad!) questions:

- Would it be standard practice for the central example.com cluster to implement a DNS server, using something like bind, to maintain all these sub-domains? Is it unsafe to have this single point as the DNS source for all these sub-domains?
- If the central cluster does not have access to the different sub-domain servers hosts APIs and cannot probe these hosts to find the sub-domain server IPs, is there a safe way for the sub-domain servers to report their IP address changes to the central example.com server?

I realize these questions are broad, quite possibly misguided, but I am looking for leads on what to study next, to put together such an infrastructure. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is indeed far too broad, The two scenarios you list, if I understood you correctly, are both valid, each with its own constraints, so there is no generic solution that works in all cases. I am not sure however what "cannot probe these hosts to find the sub-domain server IPs" really means to you in the context of the DNS, You may wish to start by reading more about the concept of DNS delegations in the tree.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. What I meant is that the central domain, and the sub domains would not be managed by the same persons. The main domain managers would not have access to the subdomain hosts provider API, and would not be able to query the providers, to see what subdomain landed what IP address. It would be up to each sub-domain server to actively contact the main domain, and report on its current IP address.

I don't know if this is feasible, or way too exposed to attacks?